# Java Generics - Bounded Type Parameters

Tags: java, generics

Let me describe my intention with an example,

```
class Base {
  public void sayHi() {
    System.out.println("Hi");
  }
}

class ChildOne extends Base {
  public void sayBye() {
    System.out.println("Bye-1");
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Base {
  public void sayBye() {
    System.out.println("Bye-2");
  }
}

public class MainClass {
  public static <T extends Base> void genericFunction(T child) {
    child.sayBye();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne();
    ChildTwo childTwo = new ChildTwo();
    genericFunction(childOne);
    genericFunction(childTwo);
  }

}
```

This code is wrong. But my intention is the child class (some already existing classes in a project) which has similar properties between them are they extend the base class and have sayBye() member function.

Is there a way to pass all the child classes as parameter to a generic function and to call the member function sayBye() (as per this example)?

Comment: No, not using the current code structure. The `sayBye` methods in the two Childs have absolutely nothing to do with each other. The fact they have the same name does not matter, it is only "coincidence". You need to move the function up into the Base class, make it abstract, and implement it in the Child classes.

Comment: Why not have them implement an interface?

Comment: The `sayBye()` method is available to `ChildOne` and its subclasses; change the signature to `void genericFunction(ChildOne child)`. Or, as @MrHug suggested, put the method you need in an interface.

Comment: Yeah I know how to make it possible through ways like interface and abstracting the code to Base class. But they are some existing code(base class) in different package and I don't want to touch them. Just want to know is it possible to make in some other way. But anyways thanks!

Comment: Then the answer is: **no**.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can either create a common base class or common interface for all the classes that have a `sayBye` method.

Then you can change the type bound of your generic type parameter:

```
public static <T extends CommonInterface> void genericFunction(T child) {
    child.sayBye();
}
```

or without generics:

```
public static void nonGenericFunction(CommonInterface child) {
    child.sayBye();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bring common functionality together without adjusting the hierarchy by introducing an interface that defines it and creating empty classes extending the common objects.

```
class Base {
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}

class ChildOne extends Base {
    public void sayBye() {
        System.out.println("Bye-1");
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Base {
    public void sayBye() {
        System.out.println("Bye-2");
    }
}

// The common functionality I want to use.
interface Bye {
    public void sayBye();
}

class ChildOneBye extends ChildOne implements Bye {
    // Don't need anything here.
}

class ChildTwoBye extends ChildTwo implements Bye {
    // Don't need anything here.
}

public static <T extends Bye> void genericFunction(T child) {
    child.sayBye();
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    Bye childOne = new ChildOneBye();
    Bye childTwo = new ChildTwoBye();
    genericFunction(childOne);
    genericFunction(childTwo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to mark the base class as abstract and have an abstract method `sayBye()`. In this way you don't need to change anything else in your codebase.

```
abstract class Base {
    public void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }

    public abstract void sayBye();
}
```

Another approach is to use interface `ByeInterface` and use it to call `sayBye()`. Here is the with the required changes.

```
interface ByeInterface {
   void sayBye();
}

class Base {
   public void sayHi() {
   System.out.println("Hi");
  }
}

 class ChildOne extends Base implements ByeInterface {
 public void sayBye() {
     System.out.println("Bye-1");
  }
}

  class ChildTwo extends Base implements ByeInterface {
  public void sayBye() {
     System.out.println("Bye-2");
 }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static <T extends ByeInterface> void genericFunction(T child) {
    child.sayBye();
 }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ChildOne childOne = new ChildOne();
       ChildTwo childTwo = new ChildTwo();
       genericFunction(childOne);
       genericFunction(childTwo);
   }

 }
```

This approach can be used if you can not mark your base class as abstract class. Using interface, you can even call it without using generic.

```
public static void nonGenericFunction(ByeInterface child) {
    child.sayBye();
}
```